# What is the interface to RIL daemon?

Tags: aosp

I know the Android HAL defines an interface for Radio Interface Layer (RIL) manufacturers to abide by, which is the one used by ril daemon to talk to vendor-specific ril shared libraries. But what I couldn't find is the interface to talk to the ril daemon itself.

How does the phone service speak to rild through `/dev/socket/rild` unix socket? and where is the source files of the phone service?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's been in my situation , you'll find the sources of the phone service that are related to RIL under `frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/RIL.java`.